# Chess puzzle: white to move

Tags: chess

In this chess puzzle, white is to move. Find a checkmate for black.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this site doesn't handle this kind of question well.  We need questions that are answerable, not "here's my stuff, isn't it cool!" -- even though it *is* cool.

Comment: This is a much better fit for the Puzzles SE

Comment: @ZeissIkon I think this question is completely on-topic here, the fact that the asker is the creator of the puzzle doesn't matter, it's a puzzle with a specific answer. It would receive better answers over at Chess SE though.

Comment: @PhilipKendall  think the edit is incorrect. It's white to move and mate. The OP's "find a checkmate for black" is most likely a mistake in translating something that means "find a way to checkmate black".

Comment: @Philip, except that the title is changed to cement the error as "black to mate", as opposed to leaving it in its more readable-as-a-mistranslation form "find a checkmate for black". That seems to be an uncomfortable change to me.

Comment: The help center says "Questions about Go problems or Chess problems are fine, even if they are static puzzles, since they are related to a dynamic game." This question is on topic.

Comment: Please don't edit to remove the question asking for a checkmate for black.

Comment: @JoeW, the right question should be: white to checkmate.  Not checkmate for black.  (the Q is about a white move that will checkmate the black player)

Comment: @Cohensius That is something for the person who wrote the question to decide. Not for someone else to come along and determine if that is what they meant. Considering this is a puzzle they designed themselves they may not realize there is no solution for black in this case.

Comment: As a note please be careful when editing a question if that edit can invalidate existing answers. It isn't fair to the people who took time to answer the question only to have it invalidated by an edit.

Comment: @Anonymous again, please do not edit this so that you invalidate the answer. We understand you made a mistake in the original question, but it's best now just to leave it.

Comment: Why is the person who wrote the question not allowed to clarify the misunderstanding? The OP's edit should be restored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either I understand it wrong, or your puzzle is flawed...

> White to move: 1. Qxg6+ Kh8 (forced) 2. Rh5+, and now either
>  2... Nxh5 3. Qg8# or
>  2... Bh6 3. Rxh6#
>  There is no checkmate for black in these variations.

Comment: 2. Qh6 can be responded to with Bxh6.

Comment: You can also do 1. Rh6, but it's pretty much the same solution, just moving things in a different order. My guess is that the puzzle is supposed to be to find a mate for white, not for black. To find a mate for the color who isn't to move, especially when the other color can repeatedly check, doesn't work.

Comment: "There is no checkmate for black in these variations." The OP is probably confused between the prepositions "of" and "for".

Comment: BTW, I don't think it matters whether one moves the rook or queen first. The rook can't be captured by the pawn (pinned), and capturing with the knight ends up in the same place capturing it after the queen is moved: the g file is left open for the queen mate.